# How to access a listview that filled in asynctask, from another class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am developing an android application that uses services. I am getting info from that service and hold json data into arraylist it is okay but I need these data from another class. I am trying to access this array list but it gives null every time I try. Here is my code:

```
public class AllVehicles extends android.app.Fragment {
public ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList= new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
public AllVehicles() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    GetAllVehicles getAllVehicles=new GetAllVehicles();
    getAllVehicles.execute("tr101", member.getAuthToken().toString(), String.valueOf(member.getMemberId()), String.valueOf(member.getFirmId()));
}
//onPostExecute of async task
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response_vehicles);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("VehicleOnlineList");                      
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    vehicle = new Vehicle();
                    vehicle_report=new Vehicle();
                    JSONArray jsonArr = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                    vehicle.setVehicleId(jsonArr.isNull(0) ? 0 : jsonArr.getInt(0));
                    vehicle.setDeviceId(jsonArr.isNull(1) ? 0 : jsonArr.getInt(1));
                    vehicle.setPlate(jsonArr.isNull(2) ? "" : jsonArr.getString(2));
                    vehicle.setVehicleName(jsonArr.isNull(3) ? "" : jsonArr.getString(3));
                    vehicleList.add(vehicle);               
                }
//The method for calling vehicleList:
public ArrayList<Vehicle> getVehicleReportList(){
        return vehicleList;
    }
```

The class that I want to call this List:

```
public class ReportActivity extends android.app.Fragment {
    Vehicle vehicle;
    AllVehicles allVehicles;
    public ReportActivity() {
    }
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report_activity, container, false);
        allVehicles=new AllVehicles();
        ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleArrayList=allVehicles.getVehicleReportList();
}
```

Comment: use static array list

Comment: Use for array list that I created in AllVehicle class?

Comment: Make your arraylist static. Doing this you will be able to access it from anywhere in your app

Comment: yes so you can access from any where

Comment: Thanks a lot it works.

Comment: nice to hear that i have added example also how to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList= new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

and use `AllVehicles.vehicleList` where ever you want to use.

Comment: Can I ask another question it is not totaly about this but I want to fill a spinner with these array list I can do this but I want add search(or filter) option to this spinner I search about this but can not find sth. useful can you help me ?

Comment: yes you can add a search filter and set notifydatasetchanged and it will be refreshed

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801712/creating-a-text-filter-like-quick-search-for-a-spinner-in-android

Comment: The first answer or second? Actually I see these answers before but cant figure it out.

Comment: I try this solution but it is insufficient actionbar_layout is not defined and so complex to understand can you edit answer for me?

Answer (score 0):

Standar way to Use the callbacks :
Make an iterface, implement in fragment and send its context to AsyncTask class

Here is Example:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Ramesh Kumar on 2/16/2016.
 */
public class AsycTaskTest extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Object>> {

    Context activity;


    InterfaceResult operations;

    public AsycTaskTest(Context activity, InterfaceResult operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        // new ProgressBar(Appli)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Object> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (operations != null)
            operations.onSuccess(result);
    }


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Object> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Vehical>   vehicleList =new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            //your code to access response_vehicles


            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response_vehicles);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("VehicleOnlineList");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
                JSONArray jsonArr = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
                vehicle.setVehicleId(jsonArr.isNull(0) ? 0 : jsonArr.getInt(0));
                vehicle.setDeviceId(jsonArr.isNull(1) ? 0 : jsonArr.getInt(1));
                vehicle.setPlate(jsonArr.isNull(2) ? "" : jsonArr.getString(2));
                vehicle.setVehicleName(jsonArr.isNull(3) ? "" : jsonArr.getString(3));
                vehicleList.add(vehicle);
            }

//        return list;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return vehicleList;

    }
```

Interface:

```
public interface InterfaceResult {
    void onSuccess(ArrayList<Object> result);
}
```

When you implement this in fragment then have to override methods of InterfaceResult and data will be pass to onSuccess of the Fragment and do what you want.

Feel Free to ask anything if you can not get.