# How to manage async task in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my activity, I use a thread to call a server and receive an XML response I put on internal storage.

After this call, I read this xml file to parse it and show information about this xml file to the user but when I add this file in my InputStream, this InputStream is null.

I guess my activity continue the simple execution and dont wait my thread so when I  create my InputStream, my xml file doesn't exist.

I made this schema corresponding to the execution of my program:

[Schema here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvKKV.png)

How can make my activity wait the end of my thread? I know this is not a good thing to freeze the main activity but I don't know how i can do.
Can I add a waiting progress bar until the end of the thread with an observer on my thread?

PS: My thread implements Runnable

/*************EDITED WITH SOLUTION*************/

First, thanks to all for your responses it makes me progress a lot.

```
//In my Activity

MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsynctask();
asynctask.execute();

//My Async class
public class MyAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "calling server...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Instance of calling class
        //Method of this instance to call the server and create a file in internal storage 
        //After that my file is stored with the server response
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        inputStream = openFileInput("myFile");                     

        data=XMl.parse(inputStream);                  
    }
}
```

I hope this post and your responses will be useful.

Comment: You should take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: If I use Async Task i don't need to create a Thread and I put all my request method in my asyncTask?

Comment: The `AsyncTask` will create the background thread for you and it has a callback `onPostExecute(...)` which is executed on the main thread when the task is done.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35434054/3965385

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            new DownloadfromInternet().execute(server_url);

        }
```

// Async Task Class
    class DownloadFromInternet extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Shows Progress Bar Dialog and then call doInBackground
    }

    // Download  File from Internet
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

        try {
        //make server call and store file in local
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return LOCAL_FILE_NAME;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String local_file_url) {
        // read local_file_url

    }
}
```

Comment: I have to create my AsyncTask in my Activity, isn't it? Below the rest of my code

Comment: yes ...AsyncTask will be in your activity.Edit your question and write code over there.

Comment: @Swodniw  Hoping your issue have been resolved but you can still ask any doubt if you have....

Comment: It's ok for me, thanks again. I added a part of my code to explain what i do finally.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that using an [AsnycTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would be suitable for your use case.

You can execute the `AsyncTask` and proceed on reading and parsing the response in `onPostExecute`.

Cheers! :D

Comment: Thanks for your help, until now I used Thread and I've never used AsyncTask.

Comment: It's quite simple once you get the hang of it. Happy coding. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask like this **on your Activity** (or a Fragment or...).
I usually implements an AsyncResponse interface to make easier reuse the AsyncTask on different Activities:

```
    MyAsyncTask m = new MyAsyncTask(randomparameters, new AsyncResponse(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object result) { 
                    // Success!! do what you want
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() { 
                   // Manage errors here
                }
            });
    m.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

If you use m.execute() instead of executeOnExecutor and you have more than one AsyncTask at same time they execute sequentally, if you use executor they execute in parallel. Do what you want or need.

The **AsyncTask class**, it have other methods you can override like onPreExecute etc.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    private AsyncResponse response;

    public MyAsyncTask(randomparameters, AsyncResponse response) {
        // Constructor
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Implements your async code (call your server)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result) {
                // Here you can return the response of the server to the activity
                response.onSuccess(response);
            } else {
                response.onError();
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is **the interface** (of course, you can customize the methods):

```
public interface AsyncResponse {

    void onSuccess(Object result);
    void onError();

}
```

All about AsyncResponse interface it's optional, but I always implement it and helps me a lot.

Comment: If you have any problem implementing this ask me, Async Task are the best way for your purpose on Android, better than Thread. And if it works mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Making your activity wait till the end of execution is not a good idea, as it will freeze the ui thread. and if the task is too long will throw ANR.
You have 2 choices:

1. Create parameters and conditions necessary for executing async task
   and then call it, providing the async task is an inner class in your
   activity, do the rest of the operations, which are dependant on your
   async task result in the onPostExecute callback of async task.
2. Create an interface which has a method that helps you communicate
       results from async task to your implementing class. This is best
       approach for testing and/or making async task as external class. I
       use that approach quite alot. In your async task define public
       method to set listener to your interface.Make your activity
       implement the interface. Once your async task is done, in
       onPostExecute, call the interface method if listener is not null. In
       your implemented method in activity, implement the logic related to
       async task result.

Setting an interface callback for async task is always a good idea if you want to use tests on it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my activity continue the simple execution and don't wait my thread so when I create my InputStream, my xml file doesn't exist.

-- correct

I your case, I suggest that you can launch a loading dialog when you fire the request. When you get the response, send the result to a handler which is running on the UI thread, override it's handleMessage method, that's where you close the dialog and show informations.

or, use AsynTask, that's more convenient.