# display text with different return value on spinner Android

Tags: java, php, android

i have this json :

```
"result": [
    {
      "nama_p": "ACEH",
      "IDProvinsi": "1"
    },
    {
      "nama_p": "SUMATERA UTARA",
      "IDProvinsi": "6728"
    },
    {
      "nama_p": "SUMATERA BARAT",
      "IDProvinsi": "12920"
    }]
```

i have been trying to get IDProvinsi value when i display nama_p on my spinner.. 
bu im fail..

this is my java code :

```
 private void getData(){
        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                            j = new JSONObject(response);

                            //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                            result = j.getJSONArray("result");

                            //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                            getProv(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void getProv(JSONArray j){
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the student to array list
                id.add(json.getString("IDProvinsi"));
                provinsi.add(json.getString("nama_p"));
                System.out.println(provinsi);

//                MyClass[] obj ={
//                        new MyClass(provinsi,id)
//                };

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner

        spinnerprov.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddLokasiActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,id));

    }
```

how do i get the value on IDProvinsi and send it to my other spinner 
i have 2 spinner
1. for display state 
2. for display city

i want to display city when value of state send to my webservice

thx stackoverflow

Comment: seems like there is no problem in json parsing just set your adapter after this `getProv(result);` function call

Comment: theres no problem till i displaying nama_p .. but how to get IDProvinsi when spinner selected sir ?

Comment: use listener on spinner , will give you position then use position to get data from your `id`  list

Comment: can u show me or give me the code or links ? or up this question please :)

Comment: it's something else , what you need to do is , first get selected item from first spinner and the initialize second spinner with appropriate city array or you can change the data of second spinner  list , try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078654/dynamic-multiple-spinners-state-city

Answer (score 0):

i have change my spinner to search spinner .. its more efficient you can see here

[[Creating a text filter (like quick search) for a Spinner in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801712/creating-a-text-filter-like-quick-search-for-a-spinner-in-android][1])